# I have 2 USB2CAN interfaces, how do I connect them together?

Tags: linux, obd-ii

I have 2 Korlan USB2CAN devices. I would like to connect them together so when one talks it sends it to the other interface and when it gets a response its send back to the originating device. I am using linux and have two interfaces at the moment can0 and can1, I tried using can-utils cangw but it only supports virtual devices.

I am using linux and have two interfaces at the moment can0 and can1, I tried using can-utils cangw but it only supports virtual devices.

Answer (score 0):

Provided they are configured the same, just open both sockets and in a loop: Select both of them for reading. If one becomes ready, read from it and write to the other one.